# Sharp corners in Table in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

The tables in Material-ui by default have rounded corners. I want them to have sharp corners.

Upon looking at some examples at [material-ui.com/components/tables/](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/), it seems that tables use paper for their styling. Paper is rounded by default but we can use the square property to make its boundary sharp. I don't know how I can achieve this with Tables.

I think that using

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
```

in some way will lead to the solution but I am unable to find it.

How can I make the corners sharp?

Thanks

Comment: The docs cover overriding styles: [Customizing components](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes)

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the style like so, `<TableContainer className={classes.container} />`. The `container` class has to have `borderRadius: 0` in it.

Comment: You can also add the prop 'square' to the TableContainer and that will also make the corners square. See the list of props the Paper api can take: https://material-ui.com/api/paper/

Answer (score 0):

Apply `style={{ borderRadius: 0 }}` on `TableCell` of `TableHead` component.